# Escaping XML characters in json

Tags: javascript, json, xml, escaping

I have a json, that may contain invalid XML characters, e.g.:

```
{
   items: [
      { id: 1, description: 'hello&nbsp;<b>world</b>&shy;' }
   ]
}
```

the values were entered into textarea by user, usually by copy and pasting. For legacy reasons, I bind properties like `description` to xml and I parse the XML later on the server.

I need to ensure that the xml with data from JSON is valid, so I need to escape the values in the json. Without escaping it it gives invalid xml:

```
<data>
   <myItems>
       <item id="1">hello&nbsp;<b>world</b>&shy;</item>
   </myItems>
</data>
```

**How do I escape the json to contain only valid xml?**

Requirement: `escape(json)` must give the same result as `escape(escape(json))`

Comment: You could URL-escape (percent encode) the user-inputted HTML inside the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I escape the json to contain only valid xml?

You don't. Escaping is done when you change the context, that is you escape the json data while you create the XML.

Comment: The problem is, that XML is created by handlebars template, which does not escape the json. XML is not 1:1 mapping to json

Comment: I don't know what "handlebars" is, but it looks as if it is getting this wrong. If it finds `&xxx` in the JSON string it should output it as `&amp;xxx` in XML.

Comment: According to the Handlebars docs (http://handlebarsjs.com), it does escape tags. But even then you can create your own escape functions.